# Help with Python: login into website

Tags: python, html, connection

I'm trying to connect to a website with Python, but I don't know how to do that.

The HTML of the website looks like that :

```
<form action="connexion.php" method="post">
  User<br />
  <input name="login_user" type="text" />
  <br />
  Password<br />
  <input name="pass_word" type="password" />
  <br />
  <input value="Connexion" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Ok, I will try to explain better ...

Here is the script to connect to a pun_bb forum :

```
import urllib
import string

host = "http://punbbforum.example.com"
username = "userxxx"
password = "passwww"
params = {
    'req_username' : username,
    'req_password' : password,
    'form_sent' : 1
    }

wclient = urllib.URLopener()

req = wclient.open(host + "/login.php?action=in", urllib.urlencode(params))
info = req.info()

if 'set-cookie' not in info:
    sys.exit(-3)

cookie = info['set-cookie']

cookie = cookie[:string.find(cookie, ';')]
wclient.addheader('Cookie', cookie);

req = wclient.open("http://punbbforum.example.com/post.php?fid=15")
print req.read()
```

But it works only with punbb websites ... I would like to create a script who it will work with this example ...

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? You mean using python for server-side scripting? Are you trying to post to `connexion.php` using python?

Comment: I want to access to my member data, but for that, i have to enter my login data. And here, via python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use urllib Module to open any website and get its HTML code. but if you want to use python to receive data from your HTML Form, you should learn one of web frameworks like: Django, webpy or Flask.

**Edit:** You should replace "req_username" with "login_user", and "req_password" with "pass_word".

Comment: I just want to access to members data via python. 

With forum punbb, i can do it, but it doesn't work with other html.

Comment: please edit your question and explain how to do this with forum punbb to clarify your question!

Comment: If this forum is yours, you can use elixir and reach to SQL Database. then you can get data of any member!

Comment: OK, you can use your script but replace "req_username" and "req_password" with the inputs names in HTML Code. or you can use mechanize as Eli Bendersky said.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module is what you need. It was designed to act as a human with a browser would - allowing you to "click" links, submit forms, login into websites, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've used for this PyQt. The window has a browser widget in which it loads the web page. After that if fills needed fields (user name and password) and submits the form. 
I think this solution has advantage over simple form submit that it works with login pages with Javascript making changes to the page after it has loaded.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
url = "http://192.168.173.66:8080"
username = "c58941376"
password = "7758"

import sys, signal

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

def JSEval(code):
    return webpage.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

def onLoadStarted():
    print "Loading started: %s" % webpage.mainFrame().url().toString()

def onLoadFinished(result):
    print "Loading finished: %s" % webpage.mainFrame().url().toString()
    if not result:
        #print "Request failed"
        return

    JSEval("_form = document.getElementsByName('authenticateForm')[0];")
    if JSEval("_form.tagName").toString() != "FORM" :
        print "Couldn't find needed form. Not a login page (wrong address or already logged in)."
        return
    JSEval("_form.username.value='%s';" % username \
        + "_form.password.value='%s';" % password \
        + "_form.submit();")
    print "Login data sent"


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

webpage = QWebPage()
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), onLoadFinished)
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadStarted()"), onLoadStarted)
webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))

web = QWebView()
web.setPage(webpage)
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```